# How to visualize "deviation"?

Tags: info-visualisation, numbers

**Problem**

I want to visualize **a value that indicates the amount of deviation** a certain resource's value is from its default value. In this specific case, **a higher deviation is bad and a low one is good**. So in short, **I want to visualize the fact that the lower the deviation, the better.** I want to visualize the actual value itself as well.

**Failed solutions**

A number with a value with a color scale going from green to red sounds like a solution, but I cannot tie a scale to absolute specific values. In other words, 0 (zero) might be green, but pure red is not necessarily 100. Next to that, I'd like to stay away from using colors for text that should be read easily anyway. Yellow text (somewhere between green and red in the scale) on top of a white background is terrible in regards to legibility.

**Question**

How should I tackle this? Are there examples that try to do similar things?

Comment: What pattern are you using to display the default and changed values? Will they be in a list, a table, a detail screen, or something else?

Comment: I read that this resource is always numeric.  Is that correct?  Is it integer, fixed-decimal, or variable-decimal?  Are there any constraints on the value (or its default)?

Comment: @StacyH They will be in a dashboard environment.

Comment: @eclarkso Always numeric: correct. Fixed-decimal to be precise. No further constraints. If a different type is more suitable, then I have no issue changing.

Comment: When you say "no further constraints:  it can be any fixed-decimal value, including negative numbers?  Is this number a measurement (i.e., output of some system) or a setting (i.e., a user input to some system)?

Comment: @eclarkso It's an absolute value (so always positive, or zero) that reflects the amount of deviation from the mean. It's a measurement. The mean is calculated.

Comment: Couple of ideas:  1) use the deviation value as the font size (with scaling/camps as necessary); 2) if you have value history, use a sparkline.

Comment: That said, if you have history of the values a la #2, then you can also calculate a standard deviation value, in which case it's pretty reasonable to come up with a color scale mapping of 0-3 s.d. values to a color scale (e.g. just black -> red to avoid legibility).

Comment: @eclarkso Thanks for your input! We do have a history, but we don't want to show it (here), as it's about the "current" deviation, regardless of its history. Calculating the s.d. would still leave me with the question of how to represent "high is bad, low is good" without actually having to explain, or having to resolve to colors (which I'd like to avoid for several reasons). Maybe this is a goes unachievable :')

Comment: The major advantage of using s.d. values is that - assuming your measurements are somewhat normally distributed - you know that nearly all of them will be <3 s.d., so you have a limited input domain onto which you can map some sort of visualization/output domain.  What that output domain is (colors, font size, bars, whatever) is a distinct problem.  It's a bit hard to say much more without additional details on the application and/or data.

Comment: @eclarkso I definitely see what you're saying. Assuming we in fact apply s.d. values as our inputs, I think I'm still unclear on how to map this to some visual component that gives the user a quick understanding of how much the value deviates and how bad or good the current situation is. Would it help to give more context? Maybe even some examples we tried?

Comment: Yes, context and examples are always helpful.